# Customizing StormCrawler

Tags: java, elasticsearch, apache-storm, stormcrawler

I have installed StormCrawler including the Elasticsearch integration. I also completed the information videos found on Youtube from the creator of StormCrawler. This was a good introduction. I am also familiar with Apache Storm.

However, I find that there's a lack of how-to information and videos about how to go from there.

Now, this raises the question how to customize StormCrawler. Between which bolts should additional functionality be implemented?  Also, how can I find out which fields are passed between these bolts, so that I find what information can be extracted? In addition, when saving documents to Elasticsearch, should I update the scheme for Elasticsearch, or can additional fields simply be send to the Elasticsearch bolt?

Answer (score 0):

> Now, this raises the question how to customize StormCrawler. Between
> which bolts should additional functionality be implemented?

well, this depends on what you want to achieve. Can you give us an example?

> Also, how
> can I find out which fields are passed between these bolts, so that I
> find what information can be extracted?

You can look at the *declareOutputFields* methods of the bolts you are using, for instance [this one for the parser bolt](https://github.com/DigitalPebble/storm-crawler/blob/master/core/src/main/java/com/digitalpebble/stormcrawler/bolt/JSoupParserBolt.java#L422). All bolts will have the URL and metadata object as input, some will have the binary content or text, depending on where they are in the chain.

> In addition, when saving
> documents to Elasticsearch, should I update the scheme for
> Elasticsearch, or can additional fields simply be send to the
> Elasticsearch bolt?

I think this is mentioned in one of the videos. ES does a pretty good job of guessing what type a field is based on its content but you might want to declare them explicitly to have full control on how they are indexed in ES.

---

Now for a practical answer based on the comment below. The good news is that all you need should already be available out of the box, no need to implement a custom bolt. What you need is the [Tika module](https://github.com/DigitalPebble/storm-crawler/tree/master/external/tika), which you will extract the text and metadata from the PDF. The difference with the README instructions is that you don't need to connect the output of the redirection bolt to the indexing bolt as you are not interested in indexing the non-PDF documents. The last thing is to to change

*parser.mimetype.whitelist* so that only PDF docs are parsed with Tika.

Don't forget to connect the Tika bolt to the statusupdaterbolt if you are using one.

Comment: Hi Julien, Thanks for your kind reply. I want to check whether the content is a pdf file, and if so, I want to process this document further. Meaning that we extract information from this file and send it, including the pdf, to Elasticsearch. However, it remains unknown where precisely this bolt should be implemented.